# EditText, TextWatcher help, Keep on getting previous string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I've implemented a view where EditText adds and removes according to the buttons pressed. I also have used TextWatcher to change the numbers into money format. Everything works fine until here.

My problem is when user inputs to first EditText and presses add button. Then when user inputs to the 2nd EditText the input concats with the first EditText string and shows up in the 2nd EditText and also first EditText gets concatenated as well. So basically both EditTexts end up with same string.
Here's my code:

```
    amount = new EditText(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etLParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            400, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    etLParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    amount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    amount.setLayoutParams(etLParams);
    amount.setId(AMOUNT);
    amount.setSingleLine();
    amount.requestFocus();
    amount.setCursorVisible(true);
    amount.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        String price="";
        private EditText newAmount = new EditText(DutchPayActivity.this);
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!s.toString().equals(price)){
                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");
                long parsed = Long.parseLong(cleanString);
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                price = nf.format(parsed);
                s.append(price); //gave me error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: 66666666666666666666666666666666

                newAmount.setText(price); //same result as before..
                newAmount.setSelection(price.length());
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I've tried onTextChanged() and implemented my custom class and so on, but just can't get it to work.

Comment: Please make your title more constructive

Comment: *"Seriously I'm getting sick of this"* - Me too. Nobody reads the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) how to ask a proper question here anymore.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Something like this would be very easy to figure out using the debugger :P

Comment: Sorry about the title, I've fixed it I hope it's better now. Other EditText is added by this method, when button is clicked this method gets called and adds another EditText to the view

Comment: I have tried debugging, but I just don't get how the value gets there...... debugger doesn't really show how it gets there..... If you need more info please ask me, I'm willing to do anything

Answer (score 1):

With your comments, the problem is clear.

The inner TexWatcher refers to `amount`, which is always the EditText created by the last run of this code.  After you run through this code twice, to create two EditTexts, to edit either of them will trigger a TextWatcher that edits the second EditText.

A solution: don't do anything with `amount` in your TextWatcher.  Use the provided [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html).

Alternatively, duplicate `amount` in a private member of your TextWatcher.

Comment: I think this might be the solution, but unfortunately I'm away from my programming computer so I can't try it... I have few questions though Julian. When you say use Editable you mean to use method like append to change the text in the EditText? and what do you mean by duplicate `amount`? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jae, Yes. Add a private member to TextWatcher which you assign to the value of `amount`.  `amount` will continue to only hold the last-created EditText, but now each TextWatcher's methods can operate on the correct EditText.

Comment: I've just tried both ways, but duplicating `amount` gave me same result... and using append gave me an error once I typed in something... I'll update the code above. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jae, you don't ever set newAmount .

Comment: Hey, @Julian I've added set newAmount like this
`private EditText newAmount = new EditText(DutchPayActivity.this);`
Still gives me same result....... is this the wrong way? DutchPayActivity is the current activity that this method is in.

Comment: @Jae ... try assigning `amount` to it.  Or rather, I've answered your original question. Ask a new question if you'd like answers to your new questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you declare your second EditText, but this line makes me suspicious

```
    amount.setId(AMOUNT);
```

Why do you set an Id for a dynamically created component? Also Could it be that the ID you set collides with an existing ID (mayhaps the id of your second EditText component?)

This problem sounds to me like you've mixed up your pointers, your listener triggers on the correct component but you "setText()" onto a pointer that does not point to the component you think it should.

Easiest way to discover this is to use the Debugger(that comes with eclipse), set a breakpoint on afterTextChanged() listener and when the breakpoint triggers inspect where your variables are pointing.
Not to mention that you can easily step through the text set process.

Good luck!

Comment: amount is actually global variable. So I don't declare another one. I just initiate it again. I put as global because the TextWatcher won't let me use it other wise.